# Un-Installing/Re-Installing Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0 on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so as a total Newbie I screwed everything up.

I tried to get slick and update to 4.0 and somehow screwed everything up.. Long story short it is probably best to uninstall all things Ruby and Rails and re-install, however no matter what directions I find online nothing works, specifically to remove it completely. Can anyone help?

I just want to upgrade to 4.0 and have Ruby 2.0 what to do? I beg you for assistance.

I am running on the latest MAC OSX and have re-installed Rails 3.2.3 however for some reason I am having trouble upgrading to Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0 I HOPE this is more clear?

Comment: What happens when you try `gem uninstall rails -a`?

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: You are missing important information, like how did you install Ruby in the first place?

Comment: Sunny -- "What happens when you try gem uninstall rails -a?" ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rails`

Answer (score 1):

What does `which gem` output? Ruby is already installed on a system level on your computer, and so if that outputs something beginning with `/Library` then that's the system path.

I'd recommend re-installing Ruby using something such as [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby).

Comment: I installed it a while back, dont remember exactly how. I believe I followed the directions on railsinstaller.org. However when trying to uninstall I followed some tips I found in stackoverflow and from what I rememebr last night I did rvm implode